# Javafx dynamic number of windows

Tags: browser, web, javafx

I started working on a java based browser. I have it so that it creates a tab and such. But now, I want it so that you can do new JBrowser and it will create a new Window. And when you right click a link it allows you to open a new window. This is my "Window" class. How should I change it to make it so I can have unlimited.

```
public class JBrowser {

    private Scene scene;
    private AnchorPane pane;
    private TabPane tabPane;
    private Button addButton;

    public JBrowser(Stage stage) {
        tabPane = new TabPane();
        pane = new AnchorPane();
        addButton = new Button("+");

        tabPane.getTabs().add(JTab.getInstance().addTab());


        addButton.setOnAction(addTab);

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(tabPane, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tabPane, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(tabPane, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(addButton, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(addButton, 10.0);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(tabPane, addButton);

        scene = new Scene(pane, 1200, 800);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("tabs.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> addTab = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(JTab.getInstance().addTab());
        }
    };
}

public class JTab {//Tab Class might need this.

    private javafx.scene.control.Tab tab;
    private BorderPane root;
    private Button reloadButton;
    private TextField field;
    private WebView view;
    private WebEngine engine;


    public static JTab getInstance() {
        return new JTab();
    }

    public javafx.scene.control.Tab addTab() {
        tab = new Tab();
        tab.setText("New Tab");
        //setGraphic

        HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Our buttons for navigation.
        reloadButton = new Button("Reload");

        //Add listeners to the buttons.
        reloadButton.setOnAction(reload);

        //The TextField for entering web addresses.
        field = new TextField("Enter URL");
        field.setPrefColumnCount(50); //make the field at least 50 columns wide.
        field.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> { //When click on field entire thing selected
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                if (field.isFocused() && !field.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    field.selectAll();
                }
            });
        });
        field.setOnKeyPressed(event -> { //When ENTER is pressed it will load page
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    loadData(field.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        //Add all out navigation nodes to the vbox.
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(reloadButton, field);

        view = new WebView();

        engine = view.getEngine();
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        loadData("google.com");

        root = new BorderPane();
        root.setPrefSize(1024, 768);
        root.setTop(hBox);
        root.setCenter(view);


        tab.setContent(root);
        return tab;
    }


    public void loadData(String URL) {
        if(!URL.startsWith("http://")) {
            URL = "http://" + URL;
            field.setText(URL);
        }
        engine.load(URL);
        // tab.setText(getTitle());
    }

    private String getTitle() {
        Document doc = engine.getDocument();
        NodeList heads = doc.getElementsByTagName("head");
        String titleText = engine.getLocation() ; // use location if page does not define a title
        if (heads.getLength() > 0) {
            Element head = (Element)heads.item(0);
            NodeList titles = head.getElementsByTagName("title");
            if (titles.getLength() > 0) {
                Node title = titles.item(0);
                titleText = title.getTextContent();
            }
        }
        return titleText;
    }

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> reload = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            engine.reload();

        }
    };
}

    public class Main extends Application { //main class

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("JBrowser");
        new JBrowser(stage);
        //new Window(stage);
        stage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public JBrowser() {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    //...
}
```

Creates a new stage which can become a window!